# iOS Swift "Extra argument in 'type' call" error when creating and calling a function

Tags: function, swift

I'm having trouble understanding why I'm getting an error when creating and calling the function below. I used two argument both of type String. Why is this producing an error?

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class PlaySoundsViewController: UIViewController {

    func prepareAudio(sound: String, type: String) -> AVAudioPlayer {
        var sound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(sound, ofType: type)!)

        var error:NSError?

        return AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: sound, error: &error)
    }

    var audioPlayer = prepareAudio(sound: "movie_quote", type: "mp3")
```

I receive the Extra argument in 'type' call error when trying to set the audioPlayer variable to the result of the prepareAudio function.

The rest of the controller is below. Ultimately, I am trying to open up the mp3 file "movie_quote" and play it at a slower speed.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func slowSpeed(sender: UIButton) {
        audioPlayer.enableRate = true
        audioPlayer.rate = 0.5
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
```

Comment: You can't set a variable on a class to a value derived from a method in that class before instanstiation. Try make it a lazy var:)

Comment: What do you mean by 'lazy var'?

Comment: Add lazy in front of var audioPlayer, making sure it will only be instantiated when it's called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the code to work the way you have it, you need `prepareAudio` to be a class method, rather than an instance method. So the resulting code should look like this:

```
class PlaySoundsViewController: UIViewController {

    class func prepareAudio(sound: String, type: String) -> AVAudioPlayer {
        var sound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(sound, ofType: type)!)

        var error:NSError?

        return AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: sound, error: &error)
}

    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer = PlaySoundsViewController.prepareAudio("movie_quote", type: "mp3")
}
```

Notice also that I changed the function call to `prepareAudio("movie_quote", type: "mp3")` because the first parameter doesn't have an external name by default. To change this, you can write `class func prepareAudio(#sound: String, type: String)` when defining the method.

Comment: It doesn't "have" to be a class variable. It can also be lazy instantiated